# Rails tag(:br) not considered as html_safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, if-statement, tags, html-safe

Answer at the end.

I currently refactoring my app, and I'm wondering how to short my "if" since I use them a lot in it :

What I want, is a line break `<br />` only if the value isn't blank, so, for now I'm writing it this way :

```
<% if @card.address.street.present? %>
 <%= @card.address.street.titleize %>
 <%= tag(:br) %> ## or plain html <br />
<% end %>
```

It works well, but I'm sure there is a less wordy way.

I tried :

```
<%= @card.address.street.titleize + tag(:br) if @card.address.street.present? %>
```

==> Washington Road '' ## br tag ain't html_safed.

if I do :

```
<%= raw @card.address.street.titleize + tag(:br) if @card.address.street.present? %>
```

Which is equal to :

```
<%== @card.address.street.titleize + tag(:br) if @card.address.street.present? %>
```

I works well, but expose my code to XSS attack.

So, I tried :

```
<%= @card.address.street.titleize + raw(tag(:br)) if @card.address.street.present? %>

<%= @card.address.street.titleize + tag(:br).html_safe if @card.address.street.present? %>

<%= @card.address.street.titleize + "<br />".html_safe if @card.address.street.present? %>
```

==> Washington Road '' ## br tag still ain't html_safed.

Sanitize give good result on this, used like that :

```
<%= sanitize(@card.address.street.titleize + tag(:br)) if @card.address.street.present? %>
```

But is this the best way to go regarding performance?

**I ended up using an helper:**

Inside helpers/application_helper

```
def line_break value
 sanitize(value) + tag(:br)
end
```

Helper is loaded inside controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
helper ApplicationHelper
```

I added this helper inside application one. If you want something less general on your app, a module would be prefered.

Sanitize used with empty parameters will check for html inside your string, and delete it.
If you want something less heavy, you can use `h()` that will escape all html instead of removing it.

In the view

```
<%= line_break(@card.address.street.titleize) if @card.address.street.present? %>
```

I know it's purely a "writing speed issue" but any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: This should be in a helper anyway.

Comment: Sure Dave, and I will use a helper. My issue is mostly the <br /> not escaped, even if I do a helper, say line_break(@card.address.street.titleize) with def line_break(value) value + tag(:br) end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because your br tag is safe or unsafe.

The street string is unsafe and when you add a safe string to an unsafe string then the result is still unsafe.

You could instead write this as

```
<%= h(@card.address.street.titleize) + tag(:br) %>
```

The h does the escaping and marks the result as safe (since it has just been escaped).

Comment: Since I'm in rails 4, and the sanitize method seems to be pretty, I ended up using <%= sanitize(@card.address.street.titleize) + tag(:br) %>
Empty parameters makes the check then remove all attempt to inject html by deleting them instead of escaping them. It fits my need, but the logic of unsafe+safe = unsafe wasn't clear for me yet, so thank you for the hint.

Comment: Thanks. Tried many, but this is the only thing that does work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out:

```
<% street = @card.address.street %>
<%= h(street.titleize) + tag(:br) if street.present? %>
```

OR (less readable but compact)

```
<%= (h(street.titleize) + tag(:br)) if ((street = @card.address.street) && street.present?) %>
```

Good Luck!

**Edit:** As Frederick Cheung's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096847/rails-tagbr-not-considered-as-html-safe/25097137?noredirect=1#comment39056536_25097137) brings my attention to `xss attack` associated with `html_safe`, I have updated the answer and using `h` for escape, Frederick. I could delete this answer, but its also showing code reduction, so may be it can help someone.

Comment: All of these allow xss

Comment: Thanks Raj.
Ain't no need to put @card.address.street inside a local variable, <%= h(@card.address.street) + tag(:br) if @card.address.street.present? %> will work fine :)

Comment: @user3181644 this was for efficiency and to avoid code repetition.. as u can see you are finding `@card.address.street` twice...

Comment: Oh ok. I agree that it looks better regarding code repetition. At first look I didn't think about the local variable for efficiency (since the query is already done in my controller), but now that's sounds interesting used this way, something I never did.

Comment: The compact version doesn't seem to work, I have to specify the global variable outside the if statement, like <%= @card.street.titleize if ((street = @card.address.street) && street.present?) %>

Comment: dont think so, whats the error in `(h(street.titleize) + tag(:br)) if ((street = @card.address.street) && street.present?)`?